# Date Renderer giving different date from the input date

Tags: date, extjs3, renderer

I am using grid in extjs 3.4 and there is a column with date in the grid.
now i want to change the date format before displaying it in the grid.
For this i am using following two ways of code

**asm_profile_date_format = 'F j, Y'**

```
column = new Ext.grid.Column({
                            header : map['label'],
                            sortable : true,
                            dataIndex : map['name'],
                            renderer :Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer(asm_profile_date_format)
                         });
```

and

```
renderer :  function(value)
               {
                     if(value == null)
                          return ' '
                     else
                     {
                            return value.format(asm_profile_date_format);;
                     }
              }
```

Here the value/input date i am getting is **19/6/2013**, but the date after the renderer i am getting is **jul 6, 2014**.

Comment: in what format are you looking for ?

Comment: @Hariharan this format "jul 6, 2014". but here the input is june 19 2013, the output date from rendeder is july 6 2014. Format is correct, output date is different from input date.

Comment: Tell me the correct input format, whether its 19/6/2013 or june 19 2013 ?

Comment: @Hariharan input format is 19/6/2013 output format is jun 19, 2013. It is giving correct format but the output date it giving is jul 6 2014.

Comment: I tried different combination, but could not make it. The root cause is, it is converting date into month (19 - 12 + 7) which implies as 12 to one more year and 7 to july month. We need to manually convert and show to the user.

Comment: @Hariharan Thanks for your help. based on your information i will make it work out.

Comment: One more thing i like to suggest, make input different format from backend. try to return in date format from backend, which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different combination, but could not make it. The root cause is, it is converting date into month (19 = 12 + 7) which implies as 12 to one more year and 7 to july month. We need to manually convert and show to the user.

One more thing i like to suggest, make the input value in different format from backend. try to return in date format, which will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Before formatting it we first parsed the date to our required format using parseDate(date, format) and then we formatted that parsed date. now it is giving correct output which we want.